Modern Stovetop Pressure Cookers - Hard to Tell if Cooking Too Hot or Not Hot Enough
Older and some modern stovetop pressure cookers use a jiggler on the vent that dances around to provide visual and audible information about how much flame to provide.  I have a T-Fal 6.3Q Secure Neo pressure cooker (not Clipso) which doesn't use a jiggler and doesn't have any type of visible pressure indicator.  You have to rely on the strength of the stream of steam coming out to determine how much flame to provide.  My question is, what is too little stream vs. too much stream?

Any significant steam coming out is "enough steam", as it is with a jiggler weight. Applying more heat will lead to more steam being released but it will not change the temperature, so for normal cooking there's no reason to apply more heat. As long as there's enough steam to make some noise, you're fine; to save energy, try to adjust the heat so that it's not very much noise.

OK, that makes sense. I was thinking that the temperature inside the pot would be proportional to the amount of flame on the burner. But then again, with non-pressure cooking, a rapid boil is not appreciably hotter than a slow boil.

When water boils, it's at a temperature determined by the pressure. Evaporating water requires five times more energy than heating the same amount of water from 0-100°C. Thus, boiling water stays at the boiling point, and won't go over that temperature as any excess energy is carried away in steam.

@Jon Exactly. With open cooking, one sometimes goes for a rolling boil instead of a simmer in order to evaporate water more quickly, or simply to increase mechanical agitation of the contents. But with pressure cooking, it’s unusual to want either of those.

@Sneftel yes, but the fast vs slow evaporation stands for pressure cooking too, especially if you want to reach a final determined moisture in the dish --- my wife does a (very nice) squid black rice in the pressure cooker in 4'30'' ---  we had to adjust exactly the time and the hub power to have repeatable outcomes ;-) https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363409/45981
